# Root distance function in Metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbf X = \Bbb R$ with distance function defined by
$d(x,y) = {|x-y|}^\alpha$ , where $\alpha \in \Bbb R$  $(0<\alpha\le1)$.

Prove that $(\Bbb R , d)$ is a metric space.

The first three properties are easy, so I only need the triangle inequality. I tried to use Bernoulli's inequality, but did not lead me to the proof.

$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$

Please help me, Spanish is my language.